# What to do with negative value in a dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

Suupose i have a dataframe with different columns. And some column contains the negative value, like
amount column containing some negative number which is not possible because the amount can't be negative so how to handle that negative number in the columns.

Comment: check the value at the point that uses it? or catch the error if it generates one?

Comment: How you deal with it depends on what caused the negative values and what you are trying to do with the data. Please update your question with more details to clarify the problem and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `Data Quality` Issue. It depends on the business, how they generated it, Is it manually or computer-generated.

Few things we can try

1. Filtering all negative values, and finding `statistics` and `root cause` and impact on the overall file.
2. If it is computer-generated, `re-calculate` with some if else condition.
3. We can make `different pipelines` for negative values, depends on the business.
4. We can drop that column if that column is not necessary, (multicollinearity issue)
5. try `Data cleaning`  and `missing values imputation`

on **df**

```
def handle_negatives(row):
    if row <0:
        # whatever  you logic
        return 0
    else:
        return row
df["col"] =df["col"].apply(handle_negatives)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to set all negative values in your column "amount" to 0 (or some other value). You can apply a lambda function to your column to replace negative values by 0, and keep positive values unchanged:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x)
```